# How to check if Scroll Lock is on or off?

Tags: java

How does one check to see if Scroll Lock is enabled on a system or not in Java?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

import java.awt.Toolkit;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();

toolkit.[getLockingKeyState](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getLockingKeyState(int))([KeyEvent.VK_SCROLL_LOCK](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#VK_SCROLL_LOCK));

Source: http://www.kodejava.org/examples/574.html

Comment: +1, this was the first answer by 2 minutes. The other is a duplicate.

Comment: This is not supported under Linux OpenJDK 6.

Answer (score 3):

use [getLockingKeyState()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getLockingKeyState%28int%29) method from [toolkit](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html)

```
Toolkit toolkit=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
toolkit.getLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_SCROLL_LOCK);
```

You can also set them ON / OFF by

```
toolkit.setLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_SCROLL_LOCK,true);
```